# Finding my data folders in 3.16

Tags: qgis

I've used older versions of QGIS at an ultra newbie level and never had this problem. I'm on Linux Mint and just installed 3.16, but can't even figure out how to get it to recognize my data folders, or even the drive that the folders are on. Even if I open QGIS from a project or layer on that drive and in those folders, when I go to save or add layers it can't even see the drive those folders are on. It keeps going to my desktop, which is the unfortunate place I first opened a file with it. The Project Home is in the folder I want to access but still QGIS can't see it. I'm stumped.

If I try to add or save a shapefile, the dialog box for browsing to my chosen location won't even show the drive that I need to access.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "QGIS can't see the folder".

Comment: OK after dozens of attempts and priming it to the right location Q can finally see the correct folder in the dialog. Yay, that should have taken 2 minutes and it took about 2 hours.